# How to check for existence of multiple levels of object parameters in PHP?

Tags: php, object

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
$user = (object) [
    'username' => 'foo',
    'post' => (object) [
        'title' => 'bar'
     ],

];
```

Now I want to get the value of the user's post's title, but I want to make sure that both `user`, `posts` and `title` are not null or undefined. Right now I'm checking for that as following:

```
if(isset($user) && $user->post && $user->post->title)
```

Is there a more elegant way?

I wasn't sure if I described it well in the title. Please correct if you know a better wording.

Comment: Are you using a framework ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking for everything is redundant. All you need to check is the lowest level property which is `$title`:

```
if (isset($user->post->title)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`isset()` accepts multiple parameters, and will return `false` unless all are set (and not `null`), so you could do this:

```
isset($user, $user->post, $user->post->title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [php 7.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op), this is much easier to achieve using the **null coalescing operator** (`??`).

> It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

So, to get the value of the field, while checking that all variables and fields are set, you can simply do:

`$title = $user->post->title ?? null`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rc1BCsIwEIXhfU7xECEtWHuA2vYg1kVrg4mkmdCMQk8fJbosiOJuFm/@z2sf46H12gtRlnDE2rgLTEBQvMNogrf9EiAdOSWFn41jZNtbUHPReApcNGzYKrTte4M9Nt3cuU1epSQ5u4DJF1bdlV3Pph5qZDRc1ZlzHE/VL9aTQe9GTGbEJ@6V/AM6EDNNqx5rhfQtVoI1ZDrkt2qMDw)